# Loading resources without XHR

Tags: javascript, jquery, qunit

During unit testing (using QUnit) an extension to a platform, I'm trying to mock up the XHR calls so that I can control the responses and test all the scenarios.

```
var XMLHttpRequest = function (i) {
    var fakeOpen = function (method, url, cache) {
        return ({"name": "Albert"});
    };
    var fakeReadyStateChange = function () {
        return 4;
    };
return {
    open: fakeOpen,
    onreadystatechange: fakeReadyStateChange
   };
};
```

The issue is that I have to inject one of the elements to test from a rather huge HTML file using JQuery get.

```
$.get('../js/setup/prequal_prechat_window.html', function (data) {
        $(data).appendTo('#PCS');
    });
```

Is there any other way to load the HTML that does not use XHR?

Comment: Use templates and in-dom HTML

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Sinon.js for this purpose, it helps your create a fake server which responds to your XMLHTTP requests as you like.

[Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org/)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I'll give it a run.